# How to show an icon in the status bar when application is running, including in the background?

Tags: android, icons, statusbar, uistatusbar

I want to put an icon in the status bar when ever my application is running, including when it is running in the background. How can I do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should be able to do this with Notification and the NotificationManager. However getting a guaranteed way to know when your application is not running is the hard part.

You can get the basic functionality of what you are desiring by doing something like:

```
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.your_app_icon,
                                             R.string.name_of_your_app, 
                                             System.currentTimeMillis());
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR
                   | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
NotificationManager notifier = (NotificationManager)
     context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notifier.notify(1, notification);
```

This code must be somewhere where you are sure will get fired when your application starts. Possibly in your application's custom Application Object's onCreate() method.

However after that things are tricky. The killing of the application can happen at anytime. So you can try to put something in the onTerminate() of the Application class too, but it's not guaranteed to be called.

```
((NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).cancel(1);
```

will be what is needed to remove the icon.

Comment: `Notification` was deprecated in API level 11. Use Notification.Builder instead.

Comment: If you use in addition `Service`, you don't have to manually remove the notificiation. When the service is stopped, the notification will be removed automatically.

("However, if you stop the service while it's still running in the foreground, then the notification is also removed." https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground)

Answer (score 10):

For new API you can use `NotificationCompat.Builder`  -

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
    .setContentTitle("Title");
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
this,
0,
resultIntent,
PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotifyMgr.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

It will show as long as your application is running and someone manually closes your application. You can always cancel your notification by calling -

```
mNotifyMgr.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
```

Comment: what will be the contents of MyActivity.class ? @mjosh

Comment: @Sarahcartenz Anything you want really

Comment: what if i dont define such a class? or keep it empty. i dont want an action once the notification is pressed for instance.

Comment: Remove this line `mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);`

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the Dev Guide "[Creating Status Bar Notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)".

One way to achieve the goal of keeping the icon there only when the application is running is to initialize the notification in `onCreate()` and call [`cancel(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#cancel%28int%29) in your `onPause()` method only if `isFinishing()` returns true.

An example:

```
private static final int NOTIFICATION_EX = 1;
private NotificationManager notificationManager;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) 
        getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    int icon = R.drawable.notification_icon;
    CharSequence tickerText = "Hello";
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);

    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence contentTitle = "My notification";
    CharSequence contentText = "Hello World!";
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MyClass.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 
        0, notificationIntent, 0);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, 
        contentText, contentIntent);

    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_EX, notification);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (isFinishing()) {
        notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_EX);
    }
}
```

Comment: This will only show you if a given activity is running. Not if the application is still running.

Comment: @Greg: Right, this example code only correctly handles a one-activity application. It is much more difficult to determine when the system has killed the application. As you mentioned, a custom `Application` class is probably the best place for the code since it persists throughout the life of the application. Clearing the notification will be difficult because the system may arbitrarily decide to kill an app's process under conditions of low memory. You might try creating a service to monitor the status since the system will try to restart the service later when more memory is available.

Comment: If you remove  `notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_EX);` from `onPause` the notification will stay in notification bar until application is fully stopped.

Answer (score 4):

It really works. 
I created a method out of the example above:

```
private void applyStatusBar(String iconTitle, int notificationId) {
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
.setContentTitle(iconTitle);
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ActMain.class);
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR|Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotifyMgr.notify(notificationId, notification);}
```

It should be called like: applyStatusBar("Statusbar Test", 10);

Comment: if I may ask, what will be the contents of ActMain.class ?