# How can i do a notification in the status bar without the expanded message in the "Notifications" window? (only want the icon)

Tags: android, notifications, statusbar

How can i do a notification in the status bar but without the expanded message in the "Notifications" window?

i mean, i need just the icon, nothing more

there is a way to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can i put an icon in the status bar when my application is running? ( PERMANENTLY, also in background mode)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973208/can-i-put-an-icon-in-the-status-bar-when-my-application-is-running-permanentl)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Quoting the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CreateANotification):

> A status bar notification requires all of the following:
>
> - An icon for the status bar
> - A title and expanded message for the expanded view (unless you define a custom expanded view)
> - A PendingIntent, to be fired when the notification is selected

Hence, you will need to have an entry in the notification drawer. Among other reasons, this is so the user has some idea what the heck your icon is there for. Remember that the goal of Android development is to make users happy. Having unexplained icons in the status bar will not make the users happy.

Comment: Pretty old answer, however I've received many queries to remove the notification while keeping the icon! Many. Same goes for the opposite removing the icon while keeping the notification, which is actually possible with some tricks. My notifications are like the percent but for other system data, hence they don't need the notification view.