# Android show the notification in the status bar without the expanded message in the “Notifications” window?

Tags: android

My requirement is almost the same as [How can i do a notification in the status bar without the expanded message in the “Notifications” window? (only want the icon)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973862/how-can-i-do-a-notification-in-the-status-bar-without-the-expanded-message-in-th), does someone have any experience or idea about this now?

Comment: The accepted answer on that question is still correct, AFAIK.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i do a notification in the status bar without the expanded message in the "Notifications" window? (only want the icon)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973862/how-can-i-do-a-notification-in-the-status-bar-without-the-expanded-message-in-th)

Comment: @CommonsWare But I saw some app have the ability to do this, please take a look android version of twitter, twitter implemented the notification without expanded msg.

Comment: I do not use the Twitter client. You are welcome to take a screenshot of the effect that you see and post it. If you cannot post images when editing your question (which may require more reputation than your current 93), post it somewhere else and link to it from your question.