# How do I show an Icon in the status bar without showing a Notification in the notification drawer?

Tags: android

I want to show an icon in the status bar while my app is running but I don't want a notification to appear when the notification drawer is expanded, how can I do that?

Comment: This is a really good question and I am looking forward to reading an adequate answer.

Comment: This goes against the entire idea of notification and is likely not possible.

Answer (score 2):

So you want to display something on the user device, that the user can't control or remove in any way nor know where it came from? Not possible...

[How can i do a notification in the status bar without the expanded message in the "Notifications" window? (only want the icon)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973862/how-can-i-do-a-notification-in-the-status-bar-without-the-expanded-message-in-th?rq=1)