# How to set custom status bar icon without notification

Tags: android

I need to show my app **icon** in the **status bar** when my app is powered on (my app has a power on and off state) to show that it is on. Is there any way to set a status bar icon without a notification like the alarm app show a alarm icon in the status bar when there is an alarm is scheduled.

Comment: Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19604960/115145) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39553676/115145).

Comment: @CommonsWare I find same question in the this site but I can't find any good solution can you please help me?

Comment: "I can't find any good solution" -- that is because there is no solution.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ok, then how did apps like alarm do the same

Comment: The OS adds the alarm icon when apps use `setAlarmClock()` on `AlarmManager`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ok. Is there any other way to notify the user that the app is on?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129697/discussion-between-ajay-and-commonsware).

Comment: "Is there any other way to notify the user that the app is on?" -- use a `Notification`. The `Notification` itself should support the user controlling the background behavior of your app.