# How to show an alarm is set in the status bar (android studio)

Tags: java, android

I have searched around but can't seem to find any definitive answer.

I have an alarm app which I want to show in the status bar if the alarm is set or not, just like the standard alarm clock your phone comes with. Surely there a way to activate/deactivate this?

Comment: Give a try to this `AlarmManager.setAlarmClock (AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo info, PendingIntent operation)` - this will show the Alarm icon on status bar and Lock screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that, you have to have a **NOTIFICATION** for that which is not removable, and when the alarm is set u enable the notification and when the alarm is off u remove it from the status bar.

refer this for more info - https://stackoverflow.com/a/45445552/6816893

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer I suspected that might be the case, I'll follow that route.