# How to show call status in status bar when app is send to background

Tags: android, android-studio

I've a phone call app which lets users to call each other. How do I show a green status bar showing call is in progress when app is sent to background? I've search a bit but can't find definite answer. 
Following post seems to be closest solution I could come across.

When you use inbuilt/native Android phone app it does exactly same.

[How to show an icon in the status bar when application is running, including in the background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973208/how-to-show-an-icon-in-the-status-bar-when-application-is-running-including-in)

Comment: is there any other android application that supports this?

Comment: As ZUNJAE already pointed app, you may need to check if it's even used in other Android apps, as the native phone app may have special privileges/customizations built in due to the fact that's an essential system app.

Comment: So it seems it can't be done at all in Android.